# ERROR WITH CDI IN LIBERTY PROFILE

Tags: websphere, cdi, websphere-liberty

i'm having problem with the libert profile CDI.

I have an application and it works fine in the WAS 8 full server, bnut when I deploy it to the liberty profile I get the following error :

ERROR   ] Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies. Bean : SecurityObserver, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.implementation.SecurityObserver], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default] does not satisfy. Details about the Injection-point: Field Injection Point, field name :  logger, Bean Owner : [SecurityObserver, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.implementation.SecurityObserver], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies. Bean : SecurityObserver, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.implementation.SecurityObserver], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default] does not satisfy. Details about the Injection-point: Field Injection Point, field name :  logger, Bean Owner : [SecurityObserver, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.implementation.SecurityObserver], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]

The solution is to disable the liberty profile CDI and use WELD.

Does someone get the same error??

I can't post the code cause I have to put the entire project, maybe if i can attach the project...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The injected object is serialized.

The problem was tha the interface is not, and at runtime the object is serializable.

After calling the IBM support, the IBM labs found an error in websphere liberty profile v8.5.0-5, and fix it int v8.5.5.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your injected field "logger" needs to be Serializable because the bean its injected into is in a passivation capable scope.  If you insist on injecting a logger, you'll need to wrap it in something serializable.